# ipad - UISplitViewController strange behaviour of Master split

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm developing `UISplitViewController` application, `Master` view is embedded into `Navigation Controller`.

Every time I segue in `Master` to a new `GroupsViewController` and then press "back" button, my `GroupsViewController` moves to the center of screen and the whole `SplitViewController` covers it vertically from top:

[image]

It happens only in landscape orientation. In portrait everything works fine.

The segue is from `NavigationBarButton` to a `GroupsViewController`

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowGroupsSegue"])
    {
        GroupsViewController *groupsController = (GroupsViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        groupsController.contactsdelegate = self;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions how can I fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it working by making sure that relevant class was returning `YES`  in `(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` for all orientations on iPad.

I have a universal project, so that particular class was still set to the appropriate iPhone settings (return YES only to `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`).

Answer (score 0):

YOU saved my day, and one more thing, for anyone has a problem like this, make sure that ALL you UIViewController's in navigation and tab controller have

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```